# Get all data related throw multiple tables with Objection.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, model, objection.js

How can I get data throw multiple tables, I have a table "Users" with relation many to many with "roles", "groups" and "permissions" and "roles" has a relation with "permissions" and "groups" to.

```
users  <-junction-table-> groups
       <-junction-table-> roles
       <-junction-table-> permissions
roles  <-junction-table-> permissions
groups <-junction-table-> permissions
```

then I could use `withGraph(permissions, groups[permissions],roles[permissions])` but the result goings to be

```
user = {
...
permissions:[....],
groups:[{...permissions:[...]}...],
roles:[{...permissions:[...]}...]
...
}
```

is not bad, but if is there a ObjectionJS way to get all permissions together it will be better. my idea is only request the data needed.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with objectionjs, it's a problem with the structure, best advice is retrieve the permissions alone, apart from being retrieved as a graph.

Comment: The question is not clear. If you want ALL the permissions then use your `Permissions` model.